# Traveling with a new passport and valid US Visa on a damaged old passport?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, airports

Unfortunately, my passport had suffered water damage during my stay in the US because of which I had to apply and get a new one.

Since my old passport contains a valid US visa, the indian embassy stamped "Passport CANCELLED. Valid visa within this passport NOT CANCELLED" on the biographical information pages and sent back both the passports to my address.
I'm supposed to carry both the old and new passport along with me whenever I travel in and out of the US.

Is there anything I should be worried about while re-entry? Please help with your suggestions.

Comment: Is the US visa water damaged as well?

Comment: @ZachLipton Thanks for replying! No, it doesn't look damaged. All the information on it is perfectly visible.